# VSTS & Bitbucket Integration

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket

Iam trying to build source code from VSTS and this required intgration with Bitbucket as source code is in Bitbucket and backend it used git.

when i tried with below link Iam getting below exception while running my build definition.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34313.visual-studio-team-services-connecting-a-bitbucket-repository.aspx

Exception:

2018-08-20T08:34:48.0780679Z fatal: unable to access 'http://***:***@bitbucket.de.eu.***.***.com:7990/scm/tes/test.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.de.eu.***.***.com
2018-08-20T08:34:48.1016544Z ##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
2018-08-20T08:34:48.1046511Z ##[debug]System.InvalidOperationException: Git fetch failed with exit code: 128

can you please help me in this case.How to proceed further to succeed my build definition.

Comment: `bitbucket.de.eu...com ` doesn't really seem like a DNS name that could be resolved, does it? Did you make a copy-paste error somewhere?

Comment: due to security reason I just gave * in place of my client name, please find below url with * bitbucket.de.eu.***.***.com

Comment: The error remains the same. You've pasted a URL that can't be resolved.

Comment: 'http://***:***@bitbucket.de.eu.***.***.com:portnumber(ex:2536)/scm/tes/test.git/'

Comment: Again. That DNS name is incorrect. Or your build server can't access the internet. Or it's a private DNS name that's on a DNS server that the build server can't access.

Comment: If dns name is correct,in this case what I can take next steps.

Comment: Enter the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

For Bitbucket Cloud source type for VSTS build pipeline, it's for the bitbucket repo hosted in **`bitbucket.org`**.

Since your repo is hosted in `bitbucket.de.eu...com`, so please select the source type as **External Git**.

[image]

Then you can add connection with your git repo URL and username and password.

[image]